# Bigquery PHP - creating a new Dataset

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am trying  to insert a new Dataset in my project:

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId("");
$client->setClientSecret("");
$client->setRedirectUri("");
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY, Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY_INSERTDATA, Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL));
$client->setState("offline");  

$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$service->datasets->insert("mynewdataset", null);
```

And I'm getting this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Google\Service\Bigquery\Resource\Datasets::insert() must be an instance of Google\Service\Bigquery\Dataset
```

How to create a Dataset object and how to configure it? is this the correct API doc? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped with my Java version: [Missing parameters when creating new table in Google BigQuery through Python API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037703/missing-parameters-when-creating-new-table-in-google-bigquery-through-python-api)

So my working Java version is this:

```
Dataset dataset = new Dataset();
dataset.setId("newdatasetid");

DatasetReference datasetReference = new DatasetReference();
datasetReference.setProjectId("bigquery-project-id");
datasetReference.setDatasetId("newdatasetid");

dataset.setDatasetReference(datasetReference);

com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets.Insert insertDataset = mBigquery.datasets().insert("bigquery-project-id", dataset);
insertDataset.execute();
```

Based on this, the second argument in PHP needs to be a Dataset that has a DatasetReference with the dataset and project IDs.

```
$datasetReference = new \Google\Service\Bigquery\DatasetReference();
$datasetReference->setDatasetId("datasetid");
$datasetReference->setProjectId("projectid");

$dataset = new \Google\Service\Bigquery\Dataset();
$dataset->setDatasetReference($datasetReference);
$this->mService->datasets->insert("projectid", $dataset);
```

As to how you would avoid these issues, I saw this doc version where some fields are marked as "required": https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/